Using bind9 with rfc2136 for certbot and manual edits for everything else
I have a bind9 file like
$TTL  129600
@ IN  SOA example.com. root.example.com. (
        1050    ; Serial
        86400   ; Refresh
        28800   ; Retry
       604800   ; Expire
        600 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN  NS  ns.super.com.
@ IN  NS  ns2.super.com.
;
@ IN  MX  10  mail.super.com.
;
www.example.com.           IN    A   10.10.10.10

Now I enable dynamic rfc2136 updates for certbot.
zone "example.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
  allow-transfer { ... }
  update-policy {
    grant certbot name _acme-challenge.www.example.com. txt;
  }    
};

After using certbot to create my 'let's encrypt' certificate (successfully), the zone file is somewhat changed, but not semantically.
But I cannot add or change any host by editing this zone file. After a bind9 restart, any changes is gone.
So, how can I use rfc2136 only for some txt records without changing my whole zone file and with the possibility of manual changes to the zone file? TIA!

Update 28.12.2024
@NikitaKipriyanov and @grawity are right: Combining manual editing and dynamic updates is no good idea.
Therefore I need a completely different approach. Because for some very good reasons, I cannot disable manual editing.
I keep this question. May be it is helpful for someone.

Not sure whether it works and I can not try it out right now, thus only as a comment: You could try creating an own zone for _acme-challenge.www.example.com. Then that zone could be edited by certbot and the other zones manually. At least having an own zone for certbot certainly works, I even have those zones on a separate nameserver.

It is not recommended to combine manual editing and dynamic updates. You can, but that'll be quite inconvenient. You typically do either one or the other, that's the good practice.
Learn how to use RFC 2136 dynamic updates by hand, or install some GUI (probably, Web GUI) that can do that. But, chances are you already have the console nsupdate utility; learn how to use it at least, man nsupdate is your friend. The typical procedure is the following.
On the server, run:
nsupdate -l

This will start a local nsupdate shell, and you type into it:
zone my-zone.example.org
update add name.my-zone.example.org 3600 A 192.0.2.5
send
quit

3600 is a record TTL of 1 hour (3600 seconds).
You don't need to specify the key for the update -l to work, as it uses a transient local key which is being regenerated every hour. That will work if your BIND is configured correctly (which it is out of the box, so will yours if you haven't meddled with its configuration too much). But it only works locally; if you want to send updates remotely (which you can indeed), you just run nsupdate without arguments and specify the Base64-encoded TSIG key in the shell using the key command, somewhere before send, just as usual RFC 2136 update proceeds.
To delete a record:
update delete name.my-zone.example.org

to delete all records with that name, or
update delete name.my-zone.example.org A

if you want to only delete all A records and keep, say, TXT or whatever, or even
update delete name.my-zone.example.org A 192.0.2.5

if there are many A records and you want to delete only this one.
Several commands can be put together into single packet and sent in one send (i.e. you can delete, then add). Also you can continue making sends before you quit the shell.
Lastly, you can send this as the "script" into nsupdate stdin. I show how I do it in non-local mode with the key in the file, just for the case:
nsupdate -k my_zone.key -v << END
server 192.0.2.2
zone my-zone.example.org
update add name.my-zone.example.org 2600 A 192.0.2.5
send
END

where the file my_zone.key is the same key file you load into the server configuration and permit in the zone policy.

Why is this better than editing a textual zone file? There are several issues with that.
First of all, dynamic updates of a textual zone will write updates first into a journal. The updates are flushed into the text zone representation periodically, but not very often. It's done for efficiency: BIND is designed to run a solid stream of queries, and text files are ill suited to be rapidly updated, so they needed some mechanism to avoid very inefficient operation.
Then, the rewritten zone file will lose all your comments and structure and anything you might want to have in there. It will be essentially generated anew from the zone as it is present in the memory at the moment of the rewrite. It will unwrap any generator expressions, reorder things (alphabetically, if my memory's right), your beautifully laid out SOA record will happen in a single long line, directives like TTL and ORIGIN will be used as BIND considers them necessary, and so on.
Last one, the procedure is somewhat cumbersome. Since there it can be possibly updated any moment, you first have to freeze the zone to stop any updates. Also, you need to apply the journal to regenerate the zone file taking the current in-memory state into consideration:
rndc freeze my-zone.example.org
rndc sync -clean my-zone.example.org

(-clean would remove the journal file, it'll be recreated at the instant of the next dynamic update).
Then, you may edit your textual zone, and reload it. If all goes well, you need to thaw it to permit dynamic updates back:
rndc reload my-zone.example.org
rndc thaw my-zone.example.org


I do not have some gui there. Therefore I prefer to edit the file manually ... and I would like to see the whole file to have an overview ... and I need to edit some dkim-settings, etc.

The only DKIM settings in DNS are the keys — these are just standard TXT records with a special name. The DMARC record is also TXT, as is SPF. Well, the thing is, all of that can be easily managed using nsupdate. Bear in mind that it is not recommended to combine manual editing and dynamic updates. You typically do either one or the other, that's the good practice. And, I expect you don't have the GUI readily, why not install it? There are Web GUIs that could use RFC2136 to edit the zone, which is what you essentially want.

freeze implies sync afterwards, and thaw implies reload beforehand. freeze + edit + thaw is sufficient.

You are right as @grawity is. Combining manual editing and dynamic updates is no good idea. Therefore I need a completely different approach, because for some very good reasons, I cannot disable manual editing.


So, how can I use rfc2136 only for some txt records without changing my whole zone file and with the possibility of manual changes to the zone file? TIA!

Extension to Nikita Kipriyanov's answer:
Use a zone transfer to download the entire zone into a file, edit it, then use nsdiff/nspatch to convert your changes into nsupdate-compatible input. The nsdiff kit also comes with a nsvi which automates this.1

https://dotat.at/prog/nsdiff/

[Edit 1]
This may also work against a zone maintained in a regular file, by diffing the zone-transfer results (old) against your local zonefile (new). Doing so would remove all externally-added records as part of the patch, since they're not in your local zonefile, but that shouldn't be an issue if the ACME cron jobs run outside of your usual working hours.
Similarly, if you keep the zonefile in CVS/Git/etc. so that nsdiff could be run against the local_old and local_new versions, you could apply your changes via RFC2136 without losing those externally-made changes, but this has a risk of desynchronization though (i.e. missed updates).

1 I also have a similar tool vireverse specifically for IPv4 rDNS zones.
[Edit 2]

I need a completely different approach

Create a dedicated dyn.example.com zone for dynamic updates, then CNAME each individual _acme-challenge subdomain into that zone.
(Don't forget to add the NS delegation records into the parent zone.)

Very nice suggestion! I myself would be accepting this answer if the question was mine. It's worth mentioning the caveat I brought up there is still present: original comments and layout of the zone file will be irreversibly lost.
